# How to export dependencies in android library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, transitive-dependency, gradle-dependencies

Since version 3.0.0, the Android Gradle Plugin allows you to export a module's dependencies to other modules.

So in my android library module I should be able to declare a dependency using `api <dependency declaration>` and access THAT dependency as an exported transitive dependency in my main app project, where I've declared my library module as a dependency.

I'm also using static file dependencies.

As an example:

I have a class `NeededEverywhere`, which is defined in its own gradle module `everywhere-module`. This module is in the same project as my library module.

```
//library module's build.gradle:
dependencies {
    api project(':everywhere-module')
}
```

In my app's build.gradle (which is in a different Android Studio project), I declare my dependency on the library, *but not the `everywhere-module`*. This should mean that `everywhere-module` is an exported transitive dependency.

```
//app project's build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation files("path/to/my/library/file.aar")
}
```

However, I can't access the class `NeededEverywhere` in my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are directly referencing an AAR.

Dependency information is not in an AAR, any more than dependency information is in a JAR. Dependency information is held in the metadata of an artifact repository, such as the POM file of a Maven-style repository.

So, the project with the library module needs to publish its AAR to an artifact repository. That could be one local to your machine (e.g., `mavenLocal()`). Then, projects that need to depend upon the library module do so from the repository, not via `file()`. Then, Gradle can get the transitive dependency information from the repository and make use of it.

Comment: I never used Maven, so the metadata stuff which Gradle normally handles automatically wasn't obvious to me. Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: @medavox: Gradle can only handle transitive dependencies automatically if the modules are in one project or if the metadata is part of an artifact in a repository. So, another solution is for you to combine these two separate projects into one larger project, so that your references are all in the same project (and, hence, the same overall Gradle configuration).